# How to find element and add class in selenium js?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can we perform add class to a specific element?

I tried `classList.add` method in javascript but no luck

```
await driver.findElement(By.css(".promotion-code-group.promo-shown .promo-selector")).classList.add("show");
```

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`

I need your knowledge in selenium js I hope you guys can guide me through this. Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can edit an element's class list using `execute_script()` function.

In the second argument in `setAttribute()` you should put existing classes plus the new ones:

```js
const element = await driver.findElement(
   By.css(".promotion-code-group.promo-shown promo-selector")
);

await driver.execute_script(
   "arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'promotion-code-group promo-shown show')", 
   element
);
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for your quick reponse^^. but about this one `'class', 'promotion-code-group promo-shown show'` I'm a having doubt that it will target my specific element.

Comment: @frustrated-dev if the locator in `element` variable is correct, `execute_script()` will target the exact element you are passing to it as an argument

Comment: You're setting the class to the parent element class, he was right the first time with: `classList.add('show')`